# ViewBuilder class with ZStack can't fill whole screen

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to practice using ViewBuilders to write well composed SwiftUI that creates a UI somewhat similar to the `Form`/`Section` APIs written into SwiftUI

The goal is that I have a class that creates a left aligned Title with a card that fills the full width of the screen and fits its content.

I wrote the following.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    private let title: String
    private let content: Content

    public init(title: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(title)
                ZStack {
                    content
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.pink)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    CardView(title: "HI") {
        Text("Text in a box")
    }
}
```

However the result does not hit the mark. The card does not fill the width of the screen even though I instructed it to do so. What is going on here?
Does it have to do with ViewBuilder()? Maybe a quirk of Text() views?

[image]

Comment: try attaching `.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)` to the `content` since this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You have increased the size of the container to full screen, but the contents inside the container are still small. Try applying sizes to the actual contents instead (before setting their background).

Comment: if you use ViewModifier instead of View you can save some lines.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a simple color as the `background` after the `frame` modifiers shows that your card is in fact fullscreen as you instructed:

[image: Demo]

What you trying to achieve is to push the boundaries of the content. So try to add the frame modifier to the `text`:

[image: Text Demo]

Or to the `content`:

[image: Content Demo]

Or the `ZStack`:

[image: ZStack Demo]

Or anywhere fills right to your needs.